# A module as an external direct product of the kernel and image of an idempotent function

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, terminology, direct-sum

> If $f:A\rightarrow A$ is an $R$-module homomorphism such that $ff=f$, show that
>   $$A=\ker f\oplus{\rm im}~f$$

Here is a part of what I made as a proof.

Let $a\in A$. $f(a)\in{\rm im}~f$, $f(a)\in A$ since $f$ is from $A$ to $A$, $a-f(a) \in A$ since $A$ is a module.

Consider $f(a-f(a))$. Since $f$ is a module homomorphism, $$f(a-f(a))=f(a)-ff(a)=f(a)-f(a)=0,$$ therefore $a-f(a)\in\ker f$. We have $a-f(a)\in\ker f$ and $f(a)\in{\rm im}~f$.
$$(a-f(a))+f(a)=a-f(a)+f(a)=a$$
So $a\in A$ can be written as the sum of an element in $\ker f$ and an element in ${\rm im}~f$ and since $\ker f$ and ${\rm im}~f$ are submodules of $A$, we have $$A=\ker f+{\rm im}~f.$$

I was also able to show that the intersection of $\ker f$ and ${\rm im}~f$ is $\{0\}$.

I showed this proof to one of my senior and he said that what I actually did in my proof was show that $A$ is the **Internal Direct Sum** of $\ker f$ and ${\rm im}~f$.

Looking back at the problem, what is asked is to prove that $A$ is the **External Direct Sum** of $\ker f$ and ${\rm im}~f$.

I got the internal and external direct sum wrong but I understand them now. Now how would I go on proving the problem?

Here are some of my questions/ideas:

1. Since I'm trying to prove that $A$ is an external direct sum may I assume that $A=X\oplus Y$ where $X$ and $Y$ are modules? Then try to prove that that $\ker f=X$ and ${\rm im}~f=Y$? Also, if $A$ is the external direct product of $\ker f$ and ${\rm im}~f$ then that means that an element in $A$ is of the form $(x,y)$ where $x\in\ker f$ and $y\in{\rm im}~f$ right? Does that mean that I have to define $f$ in $X$ and $Y$?
2. Is it possible to salvage my proof above? When does the internal direct sum equal to the external direct sum? I know that it is always the case that the two are isomorphic. If I remember correctly in groups it is possible for the internal direct product and the external direct product to be equal.

I hope you guys could clarify some things to me and point me in the right direction. Thank you!

Comment: I notice you switch from "sum" to "product" in your question, but that shouldn't impact anything because finite direct products and finite direct sums are the same thing for modules.

Comment: And good job writing up your question, btw! We wish all posters would take such care :)

Comment: When I took up group theory, what we used is direct product but now in modules we are using the term direct sum. Thank you for taking the time to reply. I'll try to understand what you posted. Thanks!

Comment: Even for groups, the direct sum and product are different in general, but again, they are identical when you are combining just two things. You didn't say anything incorrectly really, but you might brace to encounter this issue in the future :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Summary

The internal direct sum is a relationship between submodules of a module that mirrors the external direct product. These two notions, in a sense, subsume each other.

### Details

The (external) direct sum of two modules joins them into a single module while keeping copies of the original two modules which don't overlap.

So for example, if $A$ and $B$ are modules, then $A\oplus B$ is $A\times B$ with the usual module structure. Notice this module has two submodules $\bar{A}=A\times\{0\}$ and $\bar{B}=\{0\}\times B$ isomorphic to $A$ and $B$ respectively. Notice also that $\bar{A}+\bar{B}=A\times B$ and $\bar{A}\cap \bar{B}=\{0\}\times\{0\}$.

"Internal direct sums" are kind of like the inverse of that problem. Given a module $M$, are there submodules $A,B$ which only meet at $0$ and $A+B=M$? In this way, external direct sums can be though of as a type of product, and finding internal direct sums is just "factoring" with that product.

### How they are interrelated

The external direct sum $A\oplus B$ of $A$ and $B$ is an *internal* direct sum of $\bar{A}$ and $\bar{B}$. In that sense, external direct sums are internal direct sums.

In the other direction, if $N$ and $N'$ are submodules of a module $M$ such that $N+N'=M$ and $N\cap N'=\{0\}$, then you can prove that $N\times N'$ with the direct sum module structure is isomorphic to $M$ via the mapping $(n,n')\mapsto n+n'$. Notice how the mapping lines up the submodule $N\times\{0\}\subseteq N\times N'$ with $N\subseteq M$ and likewise for $N'$. In this sense, internal direct sums as external direct sums.

I don't mean to say they are identical ideas, because they are obviously not. What I mean to say is that an internal direct sum is just a reflection of an external direct sum interpreted inside a module.

### Your situation

Really, I think your proof is fine, and I'm not sure your teacher is actually looking for you to distinguish it as an external direct sum. But if you want to, you can: just form the external direct sum of the modules $\ker(f)$ and ${\rm im}(f)$, and map $A$ into this direct sum  by sending $a\mapsto (a-f(a),f(a))\in\ker(f)\times{\rm im}(f)$, explaining that this is an isomorphism.

Comment: So what I should do is define a mapping, say $\varphi:A\rightarrow Ker\,\, f\times  Im \,\,f$, with $\varphi(a)\rightarrow (a-f(a), f(a))$ show that this is an isomorphism and conclude that $A\cong  Ker\,\, f\times  Im \,\,f.$ But my idea of isomorphism is that it does not mean the two are equal but only that they have the same structure.

Comment: @chowching In algebra, you should start getting the feeling that "isomorphism is as good as equality." An isomorphism basically says "Hey, if you relabel everything, these two things have exactly the same structure." Now in your proof, when you showed that $A$ was an internal direct sum, the equality was *deserved* because as sets the two things were really equal.

Comment: @chowching To be honest, if the original problem said "external direct sum $A=B\oplus C$," I would interpret that as meaning $A\cong B\oplus C$. But if I wrote the problem with internal sums, I would say "Internal sum $A=B\oplus C$" and *not* use $\cong$.

Comment: Yes that's how I understand isomorphism. Just a relabeling of things but the structure remains intact. I have this reservation in my mind though. It seems to me that when two things are isomorphic they are not 'exactly' the same.

Comment: Thank you for your replies rschwieb. It would have been less confusing for me if the question made use of $+$ instead of $\oplus$. Besides it seems to me that $A$ is really more of an internal direct sum than an external one. Since the mapping $f$ is from $A$ to itself and the image and kernel of $f$ are both submodules of $A$. Anyway since $A$ is isomorphic to $Ker\,\,f \times Im\,\,f$ I think it's as good as it gets. Thank you!