# Galois extension of $p^2$ root of unity contains a subfield whose Galois group is $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-extensions

Let $\zeta$ be a primitive $p^2$ th root of unity with prime $p$. Let $L$ be the Galois extension   $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$,

I want to prove  $L$ contains a subfield whose Galois group is $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.

---

The followings are my trials stuck at some point.

First I know, $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ where $\zeta_n$ is the $n$th root of unity, is Galois over $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)/\mathbb{Q}) \simeq (\mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z})^{*}$,  where $*$ denote the unit group.

Hence the $\mathbb{Q}$ automorphism of $L$ is the form $\zeta \mapsto \zeta^k$ with $p$ does not divide $k$.

To show $L$ contains a subfield whose Galois group is $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, first let $K$ be a subfield of $L$, then having $\operatorname{Gal}(L/K) \simeq \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ implies $[L:K]=p$, .....

---

Is there any simple way to prove this theorem?

Comment: What is the structure of $(\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)^\times$?

Comment: Do you know what $(\mathbb{Z} / n\mathbb{Z})^*$ is?  If so, can you find its order when $n = p^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple depends.

---

It is extremely simple with some standard factors about the unit groups $(\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)^\ast$. The relevant here being:

$$
(\mathbb Z/p^n\mathbb Z)^\ast\cong\begin{cases}(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)^\ast\times\mathbb Z/p^{n-1}\mathbb Z&,p>2\\\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z/2^{n-2}\mathbb Z&,p=2\end{cases}
$$

In our case, $n=2$, we the immediately deduce that

$$
\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb Q(\zeta)/\mathbb Q)\cong\begin{cases}(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)^\ast\times\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z&,p>2\\\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z&,p=2\end{cases}
$$

which solves the exercise.

---

Alternatively, note that $\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb Q(\zeta)/\mathbb Q)$ is abelian. Hence the structure theorem applies, giving that

$$
\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb Q(\zeta)/\mathbb Q)\cong\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z\oplus\left(\bigoplus_i\mathbb Z/q_i^{e_i}\mathbb Q\right)
$$

with $q\mid p-1$. The decomposition takes this form since $(p,p-1)=1$. Fixing by the right-most summand gives the result.

---

Both of the given solutions, however, require some outside knowledge (i.e. beyond the scope of the question itself). There might be an easier, group-theoretic argument which I do not see at the moment.

---

**EDIT:** I found an interesting alternative (which only works for $n=2$ and $p>2$; $p=2$ is not that hard though). Consider taking $p$-th powers as an endomorphism $\pi$ of $(\mathbb Z/p^2\mathbb Z)^\ast$. Note that

$$
\pi^2(a)\equiv a^{p^2}\equiv a^p\equiv\pi(a)\mod p^2
$$

by Euler's theorem. Hence $\pi^2=\pi$ and it is then [straightforward](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/566685/a-module-as-an-external-direct-product-of-the-kernel-and-image-of-an-idempotent) to see that

$$
(\mathbb Z/p^2\mathbb Z)^\ast\cong\ker\pi\oplus\operatorname{im}\pi\,.
$$

Note that $\ker\pi$ consists of elements of order $p$ and that $\ker\pi\ne1$ since $p+1$ is non-trivial of order $p$ (alternatively, using Cauchy's theorem, since $p$ divides the group order). As $|(\mathbb Z/p^2\mathbb Z)^\ast|=p(p-1)$ we conclude that $\ker\pi\cong\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ and fixing by $\operatorname{im}\pi$ yields the desired conclusion.

Comment: I always enjoyed showing my students in Algebra that in $(\Bbb Z/p^n\Bbb Z)^\times$ for $p\ne2$, the $p$-Sylow subgroup is generated by $p+1$.

Comment: @Lubin Interestingly enough, I used this as my final incredient for an alternative, arguably more elementary, approach.